# How to get Rss image from parser

Tags: java, android, xml, rss

I am parsing rss and display it in android device. I can able to parse title, description, date and link. but whenever i tried to get image URL i cant able to get image url, i only getting null. I am not sure how to get image from rss feed. if anyone know how to get image from rss, please guide me. Thanks for valuable replies.

Comment: plz show up your rss feed for more information..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First step, you might want to check: http://cyber.law.harvard.edu/rss/rss.html and see that you are asking the right fields.

Also, you can use http://pipes.yahoo.com as a service to transform the rss to json and then your life will be easier on the client/andriod side.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SAX parser and its for android, please look into your RSSHandler file and add support for the media:content tag.